# Automatic category for a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I've created two new CPTs called 'Movie Reviews' and "Game Reviews". In my website I also have one category called 'Reviews' where you can find two sub-categories: 'Movie Reviews' and 'Game Reviews'.

I saw that I can set a specific taxonomy for each CPT, but what I want is to automaticly set one specific category to every post in this CPT. For example, if I write a movie review in my CPT 'Movie Reviews', I want to automaticly set the category of this post as 'Reviews' - 'Movie Reviews', because every post under this CPT will be like that.

Is this possible? How should I proceed?

Comment: This question has been answered in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49369/how-to-set-a-preset-category-for-custom-post-types=

Comment: I think you should proceed with going to the link and testing with some code.  If you run into an issue you should come back and make an [edit] with code and then we could help.  If you are wanting someone to do it for you I dont think that's going to happen.  As ville pointed this has been asked before.

Comment: I didn't see that question before, thank you @ville6000! I'll try it out now :) Anyway, I didn't know how should I start working with it and that's why I tried to ask for some help. Your rudeness isn't helping, @Darth_Vader.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude.  Just being honest.  If you don't know where to start you should explain that and at least try to show us something.  I think its rude when people expect people that have spent countless time and effort to learn something wanting answers when they don't even try.

Comment: You're assuming I'm not trying anything while I told you I tried with the taxonomy but it's not giving me what I want. I also spent countless hours trying to learn, but I'm pretty new into this. I'm not expecting you to do my job. If you read, you'll see I'm just asking for a route, as the newbie I am :) This community is supposed to be a place to share knowledge, and what you said isn't helping me to achieve nothing, just pissing me off. I'll quit the offtopic now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run an action to check post type every time a new post is being created.
Just add this code in **functions.php** in your active theme folder located in "**wp-content/themes**"

```
function post_auto_cat( $post_ID ) {
    $post_type = 'Your custom post type. For example: movie';
    $cat_id = 123; // Your reviews category id (for example: 123)
    $post_categories=array($cat_id);

    // check if current post type is movie review
    if(get_post_type($post_ID)==$post_type) {
        // assign a category for this post by default
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories );
    }

   return $post_ID;
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_auto_cat' );
```

It will assign the category for each post with the custom post type 'movie' to the category reviews with the ID 123 - EVERY time a new post gets published.

If you wanted to make this check fires every time a post is being updated (not just published) you will have to change the last line from

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_auto_cat' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_auto_cat' );
```

**Remember** to change the values in the above mentioned code to your values (post type & category id)

*This code looks legit but i didn't test so remember to backup your files/database before using it.*