# Automatically Add a Category to a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm going to be setting up a custom post type on a site (for job vacancies) and I'm going to create a separate menu item on the site's main nav using categories, and i'll use a 'jobs' category to effectively have the jobs menu item running as a second blog.

What i would like is to have it so when the client adds a job in the back end, the created post under this custom-post-type automatically has the category 'jobs' applied to it, regardless of any additional categories they use – so the posted jobs automatically get added to this menu item in the front end.

Is there a way of automatically adding a category to a custom-post-type? And also having it so any post with the category 'jobs' doesn't then show on the main blog page (which is going to be a news and market info page).

Any help would be awesome.

Emily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic category for a Custom Post Type](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208433/automatic-category-for-a-custom-post-type)

Comment: @belinus , sorry saw too late your responce but answered and hope it helps her anyway on her way. Btw there they use `cat_id` which imho is a bad example *(think about deleting the category by mistake and then recreating it, then it would having another `cat_id`  and not working anymore!)*

Comment: @Charles No problem.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the first question (pre-populate a CPT with a Cat) you could add following function to functions.php .*(make backup first svp)*

In the code below *movies* is the Custom Post Type and *horror* is the Category.
Please change to own preferences.

```
/**
 * Set a Category on Custom Post Type
 * 
 * Read more: {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/}
 *            {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug}
 *            {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms}
 *            
 */
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse261307_set_cat_on_cpt' );
function wpse261307_set_cat_on_cpt( $post_id )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Check for correct post type
    if ( get_post_type() == 'movies' ) // Set post or custom-post type name here
    {  
        // Find the Category by slug
        $idObj = get_category_by_slug( 'horror' ); // Set your Category here
        // Get the Category ID
        $id = $idObj->term_id;

       // Set now the Category for this CPT
       wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $id, 'category', true );
    }

}// end function
```

--

*I would then make a function which hides the meta-box in the back-end for this specific CPT. (so no one can add/change the category, but that is only useful when you use only 1 category pro posting)*

--

Then you will need to make a function which hide this specific CPT to be shown on the main blog page. *(by using a query to exclude the category ' jobs' on the main blog page)* .

```
/**
 * Exclude CPT with Cat jobs on Landing page
 *
 * Read more: {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug}
 *            {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms}
 *            {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_categories_on_your_main_page}
 *            {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query#Examples}
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse261307_exclude_cat_main_blog' );
function wpse261307_exclude_cat_main_blog( $query )
{   
    global $wpdb;

    // Find the Category by slug
    $idObj = get_category_by_slug( 'horror' );
    // Get the Category ID
    $id = $idObj->term_id;

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( 'cat', -$id );
    }

} // end function
```

Hope this helps you on your way.

> Note:
>   • Add this to a home brew plugin or in a `myfunctions.php` in the [wp-content/mu-plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) folder *(which you have to create yourself)*
>   • Imho the most solid solution to be sure nothing get lost *(meaning out of sight because it still is in your database)* when changing to another theme. *(changes made directly in a `template` file are not anymore visible when you change to another theme)*
>   • Btw, the same *(adding them into a myfunctions.php file in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` folder)* I would do for creating Custom Post Types.

*Ps, to clarify why I am not a fan of using `id` numbers directly:*

- It happens that a category is deleted for whatever reason and afterwards it seems a mistake and the same category needs to be created again.
- When a new category is created *(even with the same name)* it will get another `id` number and then *(when you use the number itself directly in any code)* your functions are not working anymore because of the wrong `id` number.

Answer (score 0):

Auto adding a category to a custom post type was already asked and answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208433/automatic-category-for-a-custom-post-type).

As for excluding it, then you need to write a custom `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'cat' => -1,
);

$fp_query = new WP_Query( $args )
// The Loop
if ( $fp_query->have_posts() ) {
   // Loop Code for Posts
   wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
  // No Posts Found Code
}
```

You would change the `1` to whatever number the Category ID for `jobs` is but keep it negative as this triggers an exclusion.

Comment: Please see my comment about the *not recommending* ppl to use a `cat_id` and your `post_type =`  is also not correct because it will be a custom post type amd not a regular `post`. Do not take this as a pure negative comment but just as information.

Comment: You can only do exclusions with the IDs though. At least without writing a custom function to take the slug and return the ID and then feed it into `$args` as a negative number.

Comment: I rather not go into discussion in comments and maybe I am wrong, although I doubt that I am in this case. *(please take a look at my answer and the links which explain what I do and why)*.

Comment: I'm just going by the documentation for [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)